# trying to printf a char pointer from a struct but I get a segmentation fault in C

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, printf

I am doing some work wih structs and for some reason i get a segmentation fault when i try to run my program. If I remove the printf line in printfunction the program finishes without problems, but the point is to print out what is stored in list->line.

The addLine function adds a new struct-object, puts it at the end of the list and points it to the first struct-object.

the printFunction is supposed to print out all the lines in the list.

struct:

```
typedef struct listoflines list;

struct listoflines {
    list* next; 
    char* line;
};
```

addLine function:

```
void addLine(list* firstline, char* linep) {
    list* newline = malloc(sizeof(list));
    newline->next = firstline;

    newline->line = malloc((sizeof(char) * strlen(linep) + 1));
    strcpy(newline->line, linep);

    list* currentline = firstline;

    while(currentline->next){
        if(currentline->next == firstline){
            currentline->next = newline;
            return;
        }
        else {
            currentline = currentline->next;
        }
    }
    currentline->next = newline;
}
```

printFunction function:

```
void printFunction(list* firstline){
    list* currentline = firstline;

    while(currentline->next != firstline){
        printf("%s\n", currentline->line);
        currentline = currentline->next;
    }
}
```

The addLine function has been run 4 times and the printFunction is given a pointer to the same "firstline" as the addline function.
Any help is very much appriciated. At this point I dont know what could be wrong.

Comment: How are you initialising `firstline`?

Comment: list structholder;
 memset(&structholder, 0, sizeof(list));

Comment: and then i send the address (&structholder)

Comment: Alright, it does look like the initialisation contributes to the error. Answered below with details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're initialising `firstline` with all zeros, in the first iteration of the while loop, `currentline->line` would be NULL and you get a segfault while printing that line. You can debug these sort of errors easily with `gdb`.

```
list* currentline = firstline;

while(currentline->next != firstline){
    printf("%s\n", currentline->line); /* the string here will be NULL */
    currentline = currentline->next;
}
```

A small suggestion about your implementation: You can use a struct such as this to make your program more readable:

```
struct text {
    list *firstline;
    list *lastline;
}
```

Then create an instance of the struct and pass that around instead of passing `firstline`. That way it will be more obvious that there are no lines in the text (`firstline` will be `NULL`). Also you can get rid of the `while` loop in `addLine()` since you already maintain a pointer to the last line.

Also, you can use `strdup()` from `string.h` to create a new copy of a string instead of `malloc()` and `strcpy()`.

Comment: thanks a bunch! for both the answer and the suggestions